# Minimum norm property proof (Holladay)

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

I am trying to prove the following statement for 2 sets of conditions:

$$\int_{a}^{b}[s''(x)]^2dx \leq
 \int_{a}^{b}[f''(x)]^2dx$$ for any $f \in C^2[(a,b)]$

For the following 2 conditions

> - natural conditions : $s''(a)=0$ and $s''(b)=0$
> - different set of conditions : $s'(a) = f'(a), s'(b) = f'(b) $.

I have tried the following as a first shot at this proof, and think its a common start to both conditions:

$$\int_a^b|f''(x)-s''(x)|^2dx=\int_a^b|f''(x)|^2dx-2\int_a^bf''(x)s''(x)dx+\int_a^b|s''(x)|^2dx$$ 
Rearranging this i got:
$$=\int_a^b|f''(x)|^2dx-2\int_a^b(f''(x)-s''(x)) s''(x)  dx-\int_a^b|s''(x)|^2dx$$

I think  I should now integrate by parts (according to a tip I got), twice starting with the middle integral but I don't know how to do so

Comment: I have the following so far but i am very uncertain: 
$$  \int_a^b(f''(x)-s''(x)) s''(x)  dx  =  \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{xi-1}^{xi}(f''(x)-s''(x)) s''(x)  dx  = \sum_{i=1}^{xi} (f'(x)-s'(x)) s''(x)|_{xi-1}^n  dx - \int_{xi-1}^{xi}(f'(x)-s'(x)) s'''(x) dx 
= \sum_{i=1}^n (f'(x)-s'(x)) s''(x)|_{xi-1}^{xi}  dx - (f(x)-s(x)) s'''(x) dx |_{xi-1}^{xi} $$

Comment: Do you have reference?